# redux: action is fired but not changing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, frontend

I have a problem with my code.

when I dispatch an action Of type "LOGIN"

The next component is Called with this HOC

> withHOC

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

export default function withState(WrappedComponent) {
    async function mapStateToProps(reduxState) {
       const state = await reduxState.initialReducer;
        return {
            ...state ,
        };
    }
    return connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        null
    )(function (props) {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <WrappedComponent {...props} />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    });
}
```

> DispatchFile.js

```js
const SignIn = props => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    function handleClick(){
        const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        const password = document.getElementById("password").value;

        props.dispatch({
            type: LOGIN,
            cred: {email, password}
        })
    }
    return(
        <div className={classes.inputGroup}>
            <TextField type="email" className={classes.btnColor} id="email" label="E-mail" variant="filled" />
            <TextField type="password" className={classes.btnColor} id="password" label="Password" variant="filled" />
            <Button className={classes.submit} onClick={handleClick}> Login </Button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

the action is dispatched successfully to my rootReducer

> Root Reducer File

```js
import { combineReducers} from 'redux';
import initialReducer from "./initialReducer";


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    initialReducer,
});

export default  rootReducer;
```

> initialReducer

```js
import { CREATE_NEW_USER, LOGIN, REMOVE_USER } from "../actions";
import API from "../actions/API";
let initialState = {
    id:"",
    username:"",
    profileImageUrl:"",
    token:"",
    isLogged:false,
}

export default async function initialReducer(state = initialState, action){
    
    let newState = {...state};
    switch(action.type){
        case LOGIN:
            const res = await API.login(action.cred);
            if( res.code === 200){
                console.log(res)
                if(action.cred.keepMeLogged)await localStorage.setItem("user", res.res)
                const { id, username, profileImageUrl, token} = res.res;
                return {
                    ...newState,
                    id,
                    username,
                    profileImageUrl,
                    token,
                    isLogged: true,
                }
            }
            else{
                return res
            }
     
        default:
            if(localStorage.getItem("user")){
                initialState = localStorage.getItem("user");
            }

            return newState;
    }
}
```

The action is called successfully and the API returns the correct values

now when I check my redux dev tool the state is set with an empty state `{}`

what I tried:

> searched for similar questions and tried fiddling with code but still, the redux state won't change

Comment: reducers are synchronous. you are making an async call which will finish after the reducer function has already returned. if you want to make an async call, look into thunks https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Comment: What is the point of your `withState` HOC wrapping the `connect` HOC? (*edit: Oh, I see, it's because you made your reducer `async`*) To echo what azium says, reducers are 100% synchronous ***pure*** functions, they should have absolutely zero side-effects. This is what asynchronous actions are for. See: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic

Comment: All of the `async` stuff that is going on in your reducer needs to be done either in your component or in an action creator.  When the fetching is done, **then** your reducer gets an action which contains the results and it merges those results with the existing state.

Comment: @azium this was the problem indeed thanks!